# is swf supported in ibooks? if yes how to integrate it into epub3

Tags: epub, epub3, private-pub

I need a way to integrate a swf file with all the click events into an epub3 format? i tried including text on a swf file it shows an error in tags used while validation.Please help me with this.

Thanks to every help, suggestion or any links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from the
[Liza Daly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/662625/liza-daly)
 answer and some of my research i found out that apple iOS doesn't support flash any more so it doesn't support swf in epubs. i Acheived it by using HTML5, css3 and jquery.

Answer (score 2):

While it's legal to embed a Flash file in an EPUB, Flash won't run on iOS at all, so it's not worth pursuing validation.

Comment: thank you liza can u suggest any other methods to embed a file similar to .swf. if any help on this would be very helpful...

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.threepress.org/2009/11/14/using-flash-video-in-epub/

A huge post toward the middle talks about ISO Mpeg4 and using that format for video, other suggestions talk about using a fallback image, other comments on this page that might help.
Good luck!

Comment: epub3 format... this file uses the actions from user. and act accordingly. if i use a video it would not have been suited. for that scenario. Thus i gone for HTML5, css3 and jquery. Well thanks for the Suggestion.